# Is it possible to write 2 URIs to 1 NFC Tag?

Tags: nfc, ndef

I am working with a company that has already defined a URI in the filter handling/android manifest  ex "brand://start" - the challenge is that they didn't anticipate the need to call a URL if the handset doesn't have their app installed.  I am wondering what I would encode on an NFC tag to handle their URI and a backup URL if their app is not found.

I would prefer to write a second NDEF record (url brand.domain.com/download)..

so, all that said (assuming i have no access to their manifest file) how can i encode a tag to handle both options?

Answer (score 0):

In case of an Android device, you can simply add an [Android Application Record](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar) to the NDEF message. This will ensure that when the app is not installed the user is redirected to the Play Store to install it.